# JQuery window scrolling event?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have an ad in my header and a fixed ad at the bottom of my page that is always there. I want the fixed ad to appear only if the user has scrolled under the header ad. I looked into the JQuery documentation, but I'm not really sure what I should use.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle for an example?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/axaler/3/edit

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var aTop = $('.ad').height();
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=aTop){
        alert('header just passed.');
        // instead of alert you can use to show your ad
        // something like $('#footAd').slideup();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you add the code to prevent bounce, e.g. firing too much scroll event? @Jai

Answer (score 28):

See [jQuery.scroll()](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/).  You can bind this to the window element to get your desired event hook.

On scroll, then simply check your scroll position:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if ( scrollTop > $(headerElem).offset().top ) { 
    // display add
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As a heads-up, [`scroll`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) has been deprecated in the most recent versions of jQuery in favor of `.on('scroll', handler)`. Actually, the former has always been a shortcut for the latter.

It's advisable to use the new form from now on:

```js
$(window).on('scroll', () => {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
  if (scrollTop > $(headerElem).offset().top) { 
    // display add
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the user has scrolled past the header ad, then display the footer ad.

`if($(your header ad).position().top < 0) { $(your footer ad).show() }`

Am I correct at what you are looking for?