# Javascript add class not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

Hi anyone got any ideas why my jQuery code wont work? Its embedded at the bottom of a joomla index.html file

```
  $(window).load(function(){

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
                $("#t3-mainnav").removeClass("arrowNav");
                $("#t3-mainnav").addClass("darken")

            } else {
                $("#t3-mainnav").removeClass("darken");
                $("#t3-mainnav").addClass("arrowNav");
            }

});
```

this seems to work fine though,

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    });
```

Comment: This will only run once. Is that the intended functionality?

Comment: I'm trying to have the navigation bar hide when the browser window gets just below the top of the page. I use this same code on another website I made and it works fine. Would you have any suggestions on how to do this in joomla? Thanks

Comment: Building off of [sam's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235547/javascript-add-class-not-working#comment46677213_29235547), if this isn't the intended functionality, then you may be able to wrap the code in a `window.scroll` event listener to get this working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283205/jquery-window-scrolling-event

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function(){

      if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
            $("#t3-mainnav").removeClass("arrowNav");
            $("#t3-mainnav").addClass("darken")

      } else {
            $("#t3-mainnav").removeClass("darken");
            $("#t3-mainnav").addClass("arrowNav");
      }

   })
});
```

Comment: If it works for you, mark it as an accepted answer, so others who find themselves in a similar situation can benefit from it

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){

     if($(this).scrollTop()>=10){

                $("#t3-mainnav").removeClass("arrowNav");
                $("#t3-mainnav").addClass("darken")

            } else {
                $("#t3-mainnav").removeClass("darken");
                $("#t3-mainnav").addClass("arrowNav");
            }

    });
});
```

This seemed to work guys, don't know why though :S

Thank you Alex and Sam