# Alternative to $(window).scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any alternative to `$(window).scrollTop()`? It always returns 0. I have tried everything (height auto, no conflict..) and it does not work in any browser. It must be something simple, but I just can not find it. I need to get scroll value because menu style should be different when window is scrolled. Is there any other way I can get this without scrollTop?

Here is my code:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 0) {
    console.log("no scrolled");
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    $j('header.page_header').removeClass('scrolled');
    $j('header nav.main_menu > ul > li > a').stop().animate({lineHeight: "85px"},250);
} else {
    console.log("scrolled");
    $j('header.page_header').addClass('scrolled');
    $j('header nav.main_menu > ul > li > a').stop().animate({lineHeight: "60px"},250);  
}
```

Comment: If `.scrollTop()` always returns 0, it means that you're calling it when scroll position is actually 0. Using something else won't solve that problem. Perhaps the page hasn't yet loaded completely at that point. You'll have to show more of your code for a solution.

Comment: Check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14283205/jquery-window-scrolling-event

Comment: `when window is scrolled` So set it inside window scroll handler

Comment: Here is the page: [link](http://demo.litija.com/)

Comment: @Rufflady You call it inside `$( document ).ready(function() {...});` So ya, the page isn't scrolled. Replace it with `$(window).on('scroll', function(){/*your code here*/});`

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you! You saved my life :)